Stuck on a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2 - x^{7/13}$
I have a differential equation to solve, which is
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-x^{7/13}$$
Wolfram's solution is huge and involves irrational numbers, but unfortunately provided no steps, though one useful hint it left is that it used a Bessel function of the first kind. I tried researching Bessel functions, mostly the first kind $J_{(x)}$, but couldn't get it to the form of Bessel function. It also looks very similar to Riccati equation, and while researching those, I stumbled upon Airy equation, which uses Bessel functions in its solution. Perhaps I am overlooking something simple. Would really appreciate some starting point to pivot from.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. The special functions you've mentioned are defined so as to satisfy certain differential equations. You can look up those functions and equations, and the Ansatz $y=x^af(t),,t=x^b$ will convert your problem to such an equation, apparently with $a=b=\frac{33}{26}$.

@Moo, thank you so much!! Now I wonder how did they come up with this exact solution. I checked a book referenced in that resource, and it just contains the exact same solution with no explanation. Though using this solution, you get $k=\frac{33}{26}$, which is the same as J.G. proposed using. I tried following his idea, and almost got to Riccati-type equation, but I had one odd term.

Maple CAS:
$$y! \left(x\right)=\frac{\left(-\mathrm{BesselI}! \left(-\frac{20}{33},\frac{26 x^{\frac{33}{26}}}{33}\right) c_{1}+\mathrm{BesselK}! \left(\frac{20}{33},\frac{26 x^{\frac{33}{26}}}{33}\right)\right) x^{\frac{7}{26}}}{c_{1} \mathrm{BesselI}! \left(\frac{13}{33},\frac{26 x^{\frac{33}{26}}}{33}\right)+\mathrm{BesselK}! \left(\frac{13}{33},\frac{26 x^{\frac{33}{26}}}{33}\right)}$$

$$y'=y^2-x^c$$
Let $y=-\frac{u'}{u}$
$$y'=\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2-x^c$$
$y=-\frac{u'}{u}\quad\implies\quad y'=-\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$
$$\left(-\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2-x^c=-\frac{u''}{u}+\frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$$
$$u''-x^c u=0$$
This is a second order ODE of Bessel kind. In order to bring it to standard Bessel form see Eq.(6) in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html
Eq.(7) gives the solution.
In the present case the parameters are $\alpha=\frac12$ ; $\gamma=1+\frac{c}{2}$ ; $\nu=\pm\frac{1}{c+2}$ ; $\beta=\frac{2}{c+2}$ with the change of Bessel functions of first kind to Bessel functions of second kind.
$$u(x)=C_1\sqrt{x}I_\nu(\beta x^\gamma)+C_2\sqrt{x}I_{-\nu}(\beta x^\gamma)$$
The solution of the ODE inivolves the derivative of $u(x)$ :
$$y(x)=-\frac{u'}{u}$$
where the Bessel functions of second kind $I_{\nu+1}$ and $I_{-\nu-1}$ appear.

Thank you a lot for helping out!! I'm sorry for being late with the question, but I can't understand why and how we are transitioning to Bessel functions of second kind. I thought we might need to change to modified Bessel functions for the reason of negative n, but that's not what you and others are doing and suggesting. After bringing the equation to the form (7) of provided resource, the solution only involves Bessel of the first kind due to non-integer n. So, sorry for perhaps a dumb question, but I don't understand when and how we need to change to the second kind. Thank you in advance!!
